# Fatal error while migrating Cosmos DB Emulator (MongoDB API) to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-migration, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm having a lot of issues migrating a localhost Cosmos DB database hosted in the Cosmos DB Emulator to an online Cosmos DB instance on Azure. 
I have used Microsoft's data migration tool to upload the current database, converted to JSON files, to a storage account, and using a Data Migration Service to pull the data from the storage account, to the Cosmos DB database, according to the steps shown [here](https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/mongo-to-cosmos?step=2&tabnav=true).

At the start of the migration, i get the following fatal error:

> Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'

I don't know how to proceed. Does anyone have experience with such conversions and know how to get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For when others encounter this same problem in the future: I applied the following to make this work:

- Download Mongodump [Full MongoDB Server download here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)
- Dump the Cosmos DB emulated database using mongodump
- Copy the resulting .bson and metadata files to an Azure Storage account (Blob storage)
- Get a SAS url for this account using Azure Storage Explorer
- Create a new Azure Database migration service (MongoDB => Cosmos DB (MongoDB API))
- Set Azure Storage as source, and enter the SAS url
- Set your Cosmos DB database as the target

Using mongodump, the data gets generated into a file structure which Cosmos DB understands.